# Why is it that the Yellow Rings are the only ones that are inherently evil?

Tags: dc, the-new-52, green-lantern

While reading the latest Red Lanterns (#3, Nov 2011) the leader of the Red Lantern Corps says that he wants to bring vengance to those who have caused people hatred and rage. He seems to want, when you get to his core, to help people and punish those that have caused harm to the innocent.

Why is it then? From what I know about the other rings (except for Orange since there is only 1), all the rings are at the base of it all, trying to bring order and justice to those who can't do it for themselves, with the exception of the Yellow rings.

Why don't the Yellow Lanterns also want to bring justice and order to the Universe? It seems that only Sinestro wants this goal, but the other YL's only want to bring fear to the hearts of everyone in the universe.

Comment: Someone who says, "I'm a good guy" while standing upon a mountain of bones...is probably lying.

Comment: History is written by the victor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the Red Lanterns are incapable of higher reasoning - they know only rage, and exist only to destroy.  Their leader as much as says this, and it's backed up by every red transformation we see (ESPECIALLY Guy's, he only manages to hold on as much as he did because of his green ring).

The orange rings (of which there are thousands, Larfreeze just won't share) are all about controlling and possessing everything.

Even the Star Sapphires are so focused on their goal that they use methods unconscionable to most people (kidnapping a woman caring for infants?  really?)  They kidnap, brainwash, and are extremists of the highest order.

In short, yellow isn't the only color that is inherently evil.  Red and Orange are very similar, and even Lavender isn't all goodness and light.

Comment: "Good" and "Bad" are really very vague and broad of definitions. someone acting under "the ends justify the means" or "the good of the many against the good of the few" more than likely would be viewed as bad by someone having to deal with the immediate consequences, but examining the end results or goals on their own one may consider that person to have been good.

Comment: @Xantec: No, not really.  There's such a thing as objective morality, and I can say that the actions of the Red, Orange, and Purple lanterns during the war of light were bad.

Comment: that bring up another point; who's morality?